# Fill additional space with div

Tags: css

I want a situation like this:

[image]

But when the yellow div has `height: 100%;`, there is a scrollbar.

How can I fix this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/830roLv7/

Comment: please add demo link

Comment: We can help you with it if you explain more about it or add some demo link.

Comment: you should add your css and html code, however, if you say that a scrollbar appear, then I guess is something about the `overflow` of the parent element

Comment: Good point: http://jsfiddle.net/830roLv7/

Comment: Overflow:hidden works, but if I have content that doesn't fit on the page, is it not visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to fill with color you don't need additional div:

```css
html, body{
    height: 95vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: yellow;    
}

.header{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>Header</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set an element's height at 100%, that percentage refer to the parent element, in this case the `body`, and not to the remained space. The `body` refer to the `viewport`, that is your monitor (more or less...).

So if you set the green `div`'s height at 200px and then the yellow one at 100% the total will be the full height of your monitor plus 200px => overflow!

Comment: Thanks, and how can i set the height to te full page? When I resize my window, is there whit space: the overflow! How can I set also the space on the overflow?

Comment: You can set the green height to 20% and the yellow to 80%. Should be what you want, if not please provide to us another fiddle and explain better what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
height: calc(100% - 200px);
```

Comment: Thanks, but same problem as @DesignSnippet.com

Answer (score 0):

If there is a lot of content, the div will not cover all the content:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.header{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
}

.container-base{
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>Header</div>
<div class='container-base'>Content with scrollbar :(
Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br />Lots of content<br /></div>
```

It is called overflow. So the yellow div has also to cover the overflow.
How do i have to this?